# select columns if happened on same date

Tags: sql, date, unique

I am trying to craft a query that will select multiple columns (uniqueID, IPaddress, date, country) but I would like the query only to select those records where the same IPaddress and UniqueID showed up on a given day. I have been trying ...

```
SELECT uniqueID AS uniqueID, 
IPAddress AS IPAddr,
Date AS DDate, 
Location AS Countries,
COUNT(IPAddress) AS IPCount
FROM History WHERE (uniqueID= 20677) 
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY DDate DESC, IPAddr DESC
```

But it does eliminate records where only one Ip/UniqueID showed up on one day. I really only want to find records where the **uniqueID showed up on the same day with different IPaddresses**.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I follow exactly, but sounds like you want to join a subquery:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM History a
JOIN (  SELECT uniqueID, Date, COUNT(DISTINCT IPAddress)
        FROM History 
        GROUP BY uniqueID,Date
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT IPAddress) > 1
     )b
ON a.uniqueID = b.uniqueID
AND a.date = b.date
```

EDIT: misread your with different IP addresses part, updated.

The subquery will show you all the records that have multiple ip addresses for the same uniqueID/date, then joining that to your history table shows you all the fields for the records you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by three fields, if you are looking for duplicates amongst them:

```
SELECT uniqueID, IPAddress, "Date" AS DDate, Location AS Countries,
       COUNT(IPAddress) AS IPCount
FROM History
WHERE uniqueID = 20677
GROUP BY uniqueId, IPAddress, "Date"
having IPCount > 1;
```

You dn't really need the `uniqueid` in the `group by` clause because you are selecting only one.  However, I think it makes the intention of the query clearer.

As written, this will either generate an error (because `location` is not in the aggregation clause) or return a random value for `location`, if you are using MySQL).  If the latter, try:

```
SELECT uniqueID, IPAddress, "Date" AS DDate,
       group_concat(Location) AS Countries,
       COUNT(IPAddress) AS IPCount
FROM History
WHERE uniqueID = 20677
GROUP BY uniqueId, IPAddress, "Date"
having IPCount > 1;
```

Also, naming columns after data types and functions is not  good idea.  In many databases, `date` is both a data type and a function.  Some other name, like `DateAdded` avoids this conflict.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work. The "Having" stanza cause no records to be returned, commenting out the "having" stanza does return rows but not what I am looking for.

Comment: @user2386810 . . . In that case, the triple `uniqueId, IPAddress, date` never appears twice in the data.  How is the date being stored?  You might need to change `date` to `date(date)` to get rid of any time element on it.