# How many times in a single day

Tags: sql, date, unique

On question ... [select columns if happened on same date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903966/select-columns-if-happened-on-same-date) ... I received this answer

```
SELECT a.*
FROM LicenseHistory a
JOIN (  SELECT LicenseID, date as date, COUNT(DISTINCT IPAddress,LicenseID)
    FROM LicenseHistory 
    WHERE (LicenseID= 24965)
    GROUP BY LicenseID,Date
    /*HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT IPAddress) > 1*/
     )b
ON a.LicenseID = b.LicenseID
AND a.date = b.date
order by date desc, LicenseID desc
```

Which returned these results ...

```
Date            UniqueID      Users       IPAddress      Country      Count
2013-05-14         24965       15         70.60.96.98      US          1455
2013-05-14         24965       15         72.252.247.148   US           111
2013-03-29         24965       15         184.39.241.223   US            14
```

The count is wildly wrong since a simple select such as ...

```
SELECT COUNT(Distinct IPAddress) AS DistinctIPCount
FROM LicenseHistory WHERE (LicenseID=24965)
```

reveals the count to be 123.  What I need this SQL to do is count the number of times that ID appeared on that day from that IPaddress. In other words "**how many times did 24965 appear on 2013-05-14 using IP 70.60.96.98**"

Comment: Try changing `DISTINCT IPAddress,LicenseID` to `DISTINCT IPAddress`, since `LicenseID` is in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Group By Date, uniqueID and IPAddress.

Comment: @AJP Since he wants to count IP addresses, it doesn't make sense to put it in the GROUP BY.

Comment: Changing DISTINCT IPAddress,LicenseID to DISTINCT IPAddress doesn't change the counts. They are still way too high.

Comment: @Barmar by doing group by Date, uniqueID and IPAddress will get him the count he wants. add Count(Users) or Count(Country) will get him count. atleast thats what i understood by this "how many times did 24965 appear on 2013-05-14 using IP 70.60.96.98"

Comment: I think the question needs to be clarified. I think `24965` is a LicenseID, but he's grouping by LicenseID, so he can't get a count of LicenseIDs. It's very confusing, because the SQL says LicenseID, but the results he said it returned has no such column, it has `UniqueID`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count number of rows for given ID, date and IP there is an error in the inner query, all of this columns must be in the GROUP BY statement. Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM LicenseHistory a
JOIN (  SELECT LicenseID, date as date, IPAddress, COUNT(*)
    FROM LicenseHistory 
    WHERE (LicenseID= 24965)
    GROUP BY LicenseID,Date,IPAddress
     )b
ON a.LicenseID = b.LicenseID
AND a.date = b.date
order by date desc, LicenseID desc
```

Comment: This query merely duplicates all the columns in the result list, count is still wrong.

Comment: It's because of the outer query, use only the inner to get the count:  `SELECT LicenseID, date as date, IPAddress, COUNT(*)
    FROM LicenseHistory 
    WHERE (LicenseID= 24965)
    GROUP BY LicenseID,Date,IPAddress`